# How to make a reset button AR Core examples in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

Hi i am actually newbie in Unity development and making my first project in AR i just wanted to ask how to make a reset button in "Hello ARCore" example i know how to add buttons in canvas just wanted to know the function in script to be used. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this unity reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html
An example would be:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    public class something : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void restart()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("YOUR_SCENE_NAME");
        }
    }
```

It is pretty self-explanatory, but if you need some more help (or a more in depth explanation) I am happy to help you out.